# How to show Firebase photos in gridview?

Tags: android, gridview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I have Firebase users and the posts they did. I want to get the post image URL from the post, download them and show them in a gridview.

This is my code:

```
public class Profile extends Fragment {


  private CircleImageView mprofilePic;
  private TextView mUsername, mBio;
  private GridView mGridView;

  private Uri mImageUri = null;
  private FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
  private StorageReference mStorageImage;
  private DatabaseReference mdatabaseUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");


  private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
  private FirebaseUser mCurrentUser;
  private DatabaseReference userposts;

  private static final int GALLERY_REQUEST = 1;

  public static Profile newInstance() {
    return new Profile();
  }

  @Nullable
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View profileView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mCurrentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    userposts = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(mCurrentUser.getUid()).child("posts");


    mprofilePic = (CircleImageView) profileView.findViewById(R.id.profile_picture);
    mUsername = (TextView) profileView.findViewById(R.id.profile_username);
    mBio = (TextView) profileView.findViewById(R.id.profile_bio);

    mGridView = (GridView) profileView.findViewById(R.id.gridview);


    mdatabaseUsers.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child("image")
      .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          String imageUrl = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
          Glide.with(getContext()).load(imageUrl).into(mprofilePic);
          //mprofilePic.setImageURI(Uri.parse(imageUrl));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
      });
    mdatabaseUsers.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child("Name").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String username = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
        mUsername.setText(username);
      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

      }
    });


    return profileView;
  }

}
```

[image: this is the firebase database]

What I need is to get the current user and get the child (posts) and the child (image) then download it and put it in the grid view, and run to the next post and get the second post image and so on.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**1. Declare these**

```
Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
Firebase ref = new Firebase(YOUR_FIREBASE_URL);
```

**2. You can use addChildEventListener**

```
ref.child("Users/w3.....")
                .child("posts")
                .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String s) {
                        Map<String, Object> value = (Map<String, Object>) snapshot.getValue();
                        String img = value.get(Constants.chnl_msg).toString(); // your image url
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot snapshot, String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                    }
                });
```

**3. or addListenerForSingleValueEvent**

```
ref.child("Users/w3.....")
                .child("posts").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Map<String, Object> value = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                String img = value.get(Constants.chnl_msg).toString(); // your image url
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });
```